# Waiting daemon thread hangs application

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool

I have written a multi threaded application , which was running fine until now
this morning i get error like

```
*

          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.useContextualLobCreation(JdbcSupportLoader.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.loadJdbcSupport(JdbcSupportLoader.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        - locked <0x00002aad4fe39460> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        - locked <0x00002aad4fa2c448> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.myco.myproduct.util.CommonUtil.getProductQARulesContext(CommonUtil.java:383)
        at com.myco.myproduct.SomeLauncher.initializeSpringBeans(SomeLauncher.java:336)
        at com.myco.myproduct.SomeLauncher.main(SomeLauncher.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.myco.launcher.Main$1.run(Main.java:278)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005aa7c000 nid=0x48fd runnable [0x000000004163f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e716618> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:34)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a94a800 nid=0x48f9 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a947800 nid=0x48f8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a943000 nid=0x48f7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a941000 nid=0x48f6 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a908800 nid=0x48f5 in Object.wait() [0x0000000041dcd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aad4e5c11e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e5c11e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a906800 nid=0x48f4 in Object.wait() [0x0000000041ccc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aad4e5c1048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e5c1048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a900000 nid=0x48f3 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8a6000 nid=0x48eb runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8a8000 nid=0x48ec runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8aa000 nid=0x48ed runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8ab800 nid=0x48ee runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8ad800 nid=0x48ef runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8af800 nid=0x48f0 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8b1000 nid=0x48f1 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8b3000 nid=0x48f2 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaea400c800 nid=0x48fe waiting on condition

JNI global references: 843

[xyz] /srv/net/gigs_int1/x_xyz_pqd (x_xyz_pqd) $  /ms/dist/myco/sun/jdk/1.6.0_16-x86_64/bin/jstack 18665
2014-03-19 06:30:55
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005b524800 nid=0x6cb8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaea400d800 nid=0x48ea waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaea4022800 nid=0x48ff runnable [0x0000000040db8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIClob.createTemporaryLob(T4C8TTIClob.java:530)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createTemporaryClob(T4CConnection.java:3209)
        - locked <0x00002aad5b4022e8> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createClob(PhysicalConnection.java:9371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:582)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.useContextualLobCreation(JdbcSupportLoader.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.loadJdbcSupport(JdbcSupportLoader.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        - locked <0x00002aad4fe39460> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        - locked <0x00002aad4fa2c448> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.myco.myproduct.util.CommonUtil.getProductQARulesContext(CommonUtil.java:383)
        at com.myco.myproduct.SomeLauncher.initializeSpringBeans(SomeLauncher.java:336)
        at com.myco.myproduct.SomeLauncher.main(SomeLauncher.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.myco.launcher.Main$1.run(Main.java:278)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005aa7c000 nid=0x48fd runnable [0x000000004163f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e716618> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:34)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a94a800 nid=0x48f9 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a947800 nid=0x48f8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a943000 nid=0x48f7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a941000 nid=0x48f6 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a908800 nid=0x48f5 in Object.wait() [0x0000000041dcd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aad4e5c11e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e5c11e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a906800 nid=0x48f4 in Object.wait() [0x0000000041ccc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aad4e5c1048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0x00002aad4e5c1048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a900000 nid=0x48f3 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8a6000 nid=0x48eb runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8a8000 nid=0x48ec runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8aa000 nid=0x48ed runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8ab800 nid=0x48ee runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8ad800 nid=0x48ef runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8af800 nid=0x48f0 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8b1000 nid=0x48f1 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000005a8b3000 nid=0x48f2 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaea400c800 nid=0x48fe waiting on condition

JNI global references: 843
```

*
What i understand is two different JVM daemon thread are waiting on different objects [0x0000000041ccc000] and [0x0000000041dcd000] so i am not sure why the app stops running

I tried the following

1) killing process and restarting , similar issue

2) my default thread count in pool is 24 ... but when i run the same code + on same data with pool size as 10 then it "sometime" it runs fine , other times it gives same error

Will appreciate any light on debugging this

Facing some admin related permission issue to connect jvisualVM from my local windows machine to linux server , will appreciate if i can use standard jdk/bin/ utilities to solve / debug this.

Comment: This is not an error really. It is a thread dump showing you that a daemon finalizer is waiting for an object to finish up so that GC can reclaim it. This is not abnormal, unless the finalizer is waiting forever to claim the object. Unless you have blocked threads  for extended periods of time or a VM reporting a deadlock, this may not be the source of the problem. Get a full thread dump of the server using `jvisualVM` to check on the other threads. I'd start there.

Comment: These threads are related to running the finalize() method of finalizable objects before they get garbage collected. The finalizer thread is waiting on the finalizer queue, meaning that the queue is simply empty. This is definitely not a problem. You should check the full thread dump, as well as you logs.

Comment: @DeepakBeta I think the finalizer thread is waiting for something to finalize. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @Lav is that the entire text you got?

Comment: added more stack trace .... is it because of - locked <0x00002aad4fe39460> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap) ... is there a dead lock at com.myco.myproduct.util.CommonUtil.getProductQARulesContext(CommonUtil.java:383)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any JVM issues from the visible stack trace.

One of your thread is waiting for response from the DB

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

This is likely what appears to be hanging. If so that's a DB issue. There are few possibilities here. Most likely causes include: severe performance problem, locked DB resource by a lingering connection (this happens sometimes when you forcefully kill your app.) and network issue.

Comment: sounds the case ... how can i confirm locked DB resource or network issue ? performace problem i dont think so ... as code was running fine till yesterday

Comment: @Lav: If it is caused by a lingering connection, the easiest way is to reboot the DB and see if that fixes it. To see if's network, try if other tools that use network (like ping) are also affected. For performance, this is still possible if there are writes to the DB (e.g. you could have added many more rows to a table etc.)

Comment: yes performance when saving to DB has been a concern .... in the app off lately ... as we are testing for more and more data ... i am planning to start more than 1 thread ... to save results in same table ... not v sure if that will cause some DB level lock or concerns .... I have all the results stored in a BlockingQueue and i am planning to start more than 1 thread to save from BlockingQueue to DB ( all in same table)

Comment: @Lav: Note that you can lose ACID characteristics if you do that. Also    in a typical situation where the saves are initiated by user input, connection pools (which limit the concurrency instead of increasing it) are usually more adequate as a concurrency control. I wouldn't worry about lock contention upfront as long as you are not locking something like a table; DBs are supposed to be good at handling that.